# Validation is failing in dotnet ModelState.IsValid is invalid, "The value '' is invalid."

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am new to dotnet core, i am trying to validate my fields firstname and lastname, the jquery validation is working good, but `ModelState.IsValid` is failing

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Players player)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) { 

        db.Players.Add(player);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Players");
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelState.Values.Select(e => e.Errors).ToList()));
    }

    //return View(player);
}
```

Model

```
namespace soccerleague.Models
{
    public partial class Players
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Model Description.")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model soccerleague.Models.Players

<section class="content-header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>Player Add</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Player Add</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</section>

<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="Create">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-secondary">
                <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">General</h3>

                <div class="card-tools">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
                    <i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Firstname)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Firstname, new {@class="form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Lastname</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Lastname, new {@class="form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lastname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Birthday</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Birthday" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <a asp-controller="Players" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success float-right">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>    
</section>
```

and this is what returning:

> [[{"Exception":null,"ErrorMessage":"The value '' is
>   invalid."}],[],[]]

Comment: What is the data of Players?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please show us the client side code with the model being passed and all it's values. This will really help us out.

Comment: I added the html of the view, it is validating with jquery, but on the server side it is not passing the ModelState.IsValid, and i am filling the firstname and lastname

Comment: debug the model state and show us which property is causing this error